# Continuous surjective function from $[0,1] \rightarrow$ lexicographical order

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-topology

This is a follow up question to the question I asked here:
[The range of a continuous function on the order topology is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846425/the-range-of-a-continuous-function-on-the-order-topology-is-convex/1846514#1846514)

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ denote the unit square with the lexicographical order. Suppose that $f:[0,1] \rightarrow  X$ is continuous, where $[0,1]$ has the usual topology and $f:(0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1) = (1,1)$

a. Show that $f$ is surjective.

b. Show that there are no functions with properties described above.

Attempt at a solution: 
a.Since the range of a continuous function from the usual topology to a linear order topology is convex as proven in the linked question and since $f:(0) = (0,0)$ and $f(1) = (1,1)$ then $(f(0), f(1)) \subseteq f([0,1])$ for the interval defined over $X$, so for every $p \in X \  \exists \  x \in [0,1]$ s.t $f(x) = p$ and hence, $f$ is surjective.

b. I think this function won't be continuous, for given $\left|x - y\right| < \delta$, $f(x) < f(y)$ where $f(y)$ is of the form $(a, 0)$; $\left|f(y) - f(x)\right| < \varepsilon$ since $f(y)$ does not have an immediate predecessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for surjectivity is fine, but your argument for (b) doesn’t really make sense: no point in either ordered set has an immediate predecessor. Here’s a pretty big HINT:

For each $x\in[0,1]$ let $U_x=\{x\}\times(0,1)$; then $U_x$ is open in $W$, and the sets $U_x$ are pairwise disjoint. Now suppose that $f$ is continuous, and consider the sets $f^{-1}[U_x]$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: So $f^{-1}[U_x]$ will be non-empty pairwise disjoint open sets in [0,1] and the complement of each $f^{-1}[U_x]$ will be open, so we have non-trivial clopen sets ?

Comment: @JayK: There’s no reason to expect the complements of the sets $f^{-1}[U_x]$ to be open. However, those sets are an *uncountable* family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $[0,1]$; is that possible?

Comment: @Briam M. Scott, sorry but why can't they be uncountable, the reals in the interval [0,1] are uncountable

Comment: @JayK: But each of them has to contain a rational, and since the sets are pairwise disjoint, no two of those rationals can be the same.

Comment: omg of course thank you so much !!1

Comment: @JayK: You’re welcome!